# Most Sixes on a Ground by a Player - Cricket

Tags: cricket

I want to know which player has hit most **international sixes** on a single cricket ground? It would be better if answers would show all 4 categories:

- All (Test/ODI/T20I combined)
- Tests
- ODIs
- T20Is

Comment: To difficult to get the statistics I guess....

Comment: It's hard to find out for each ground, but then you can like find out who scored the max number of sixes in different formats. http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/records/283123.html > ODI
http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/records/305202.html > t20

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **All** - Shahid Afridi (Pak)-71-Sharjah Cricket Stadium, U.A.E
- **Test** -CL Cairns (NZ)-23-Eden Park, Auckland, New Zealand
- **ODI** - Shahid Afridi (Pak)-65-Sharjah Cricket Stadium, U.A.E
- **T20I** - MJ Guptill (NZ)-19-Eden Park, Auckland, New Zealand
- Source: ESPN Cricinfo Statsguru
- [All]: http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/stats/index.html?class=11;filter=advanced;orderby=sixes;template=results;type=batting;view=ground
- [Test]:http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/stats/index.html?class=1;filter=advanced;orderby=sixes;template=results;type=batting;view=ground

I apparently can't post more than two links because my reputation is less than 10! You can click on ODI and T20I header on the stat page to get the other sources.

Comment: Do you have sources for these numbers?

Comment: @Nij Edited the answer to include the source

Comment: Simply naming a website is not giving a source. There is no easy way to check the numbers stated.

Comment: @Nij I hope this answers your doubts.